# Book about a boy in a world where people lived underground and were ruled by a lizard god

Tags: story-identification, novel, underground-civilization

I remember it was set in a world where people lived underground and were ruled by some lizard god, I think. There was this boy who was from this cursed family or something and they would have to send a boy to fight the lizard god when he turned 18, I think. But the lizard was always too strong and killed each generation of men that came. However, this time something happened and the boy ending up killing the god with his father's sword, I think. Then he returned to the village, but they kicked him out because another lizard god would come and seek revenge. So he sets out on his own.

That's all I can remember. P.S. this all happens at the beginning of the book.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you read this and when do you think it might've been published? Also, do you recall anything about the cover?